# FOREIGN KEY y REFERENCES SQL (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

¡Buenas!, resulta que tengo una base de datos creada en localhost de mysql (La cree ahí solo porque no la voy a usar para algún proyecto, es una tarea de la U), esta base de datos se llama datos_empresa, y dentro de esta base de datos, tengo una tabla creada llamada clientes, esta tabla tiene los siguientes campos:

```
id_cliente (Es un tipo int y es la llave primaria),
nombre_cliente (Tipo varchar 35 caracteres)
```

Luego necesito crear otra tabla, esta tabla quiero que tenga el nombre productos, y quiero que contenga los siguientes campos:

```
codigo (Tipo varchar 25 caracteres PRIMARY KEY),
nombre (Tipo varchar 60 caracteres UNIQUE NOT NULL),
precio (Tipo decimal),
id_cliente (Tipo int FOREIGN KEY(id_cliente) REFERENCES clientes(id_cliente))
```

La información de arriba es la maqueta de la tabla, y la sintaxis que use para intentar crear esta tabla es la siguiente:

```
CREATE TABLE productos(

codigo varchar(25) PRIMARY KEY,
nombre varchar(60) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
precio decimal,
id_cliente int FOREIGN KEY(id_cliente) REFERENCES clientes(id_cliente)

);
```

Esto me arroja el siguiente error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'FOREIGN KEY(id_cliente) REFERENCES clientes(id_cliente))' at line 1
MariaDB [datos_empresa]>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes intentar usando *back-ticks* **`** para separar los identificadores, además de separarlo en dos líneas

```
id_cliente int,
FOREIGN KEY(`id_cliente`) REFERENCES `clientes`(`id_cliente`)
```

Comment: Ahora me sale: 
ERROR 1072 (42000): Key column 'clientes' doesn't exist in table.

Comment: Ah ya vi el error... esta vez es de tipeo...

Comment: ¡Funcióna!, ¡muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Efectivamente, sólo te faltaba una coma:

```
CREATE TABLE clientes(
  id_cliente int AUTO_INCREMENT,
  cliente varchar(127),
  PRIMARY KEY(id_cliente)
  );

CREATE TABLE productos(
codigo varchar(25) PRIMARY KEY,
nombre varchar(60) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
precio decimal,
id_cliente int,
FOREIGN KEY(id_cliente) REFERENCES clientes(id_cliente)
);
```